# Is there a way to clone form field values in jQuery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

jQuery has a `clone()` function that clones the actual form with no problem, but it doesn't preserve any values that have been entered into the form.

Is there a way to get around this?

Sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? A quick test has no issues here: http://jsfiddle.net/meGyg/

Comment: I think the issue is if you change the data via the form, and then try to clone it. Forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F9aWu/ Try to change the form, then click clone.

Comment: ya @[nick craver]'s solution works fine except for the textarea part

Comment: The initial representation of the form controls goes out of sync with the DOM when we start modifying properties such as `value`, and `checked` directly. When we clone a node, the representation of each DOM node gets copied which does not include object properties such as `value`. One solution is to copy the relevant properties - (value, checked, selected) for each form control into the cloned nodes. The other is to modify the element whenever making a change. So instead of element.val('something'), do element.setAttribute('value', 'something') which should work find when cloning.

Answer (score 27):

ran into the same problem, simple solution:

```
// touch all input values
$('input:text').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});

var clones = $('input:text').clone();
```

the trick is that this will change the actual 'value' attribute in the DOM tree, otherwise the data you enter 'on-the-fly' only exists in the DOM 'state'

Comment: Would this not need to be escaped?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I don't think so, text input can't display HTML, you're setting it to the value it already had before, and quotes are not an issue because you are setting a string attribute value instead of printing plain HTML code.

Comment: this is effective for input:text, but what about checkboxes, radio buttons, text areas and the like?

Answer (score 8):

Stemming from the notes, here's a solution. With the following form:

```
<form id="old">
    <textarea>Some Value</textarea>
    <input type="text" value="Some Value" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="bob" checked />
    <br />
</form>

<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />
```

This jQuery works, including the textareas:

```
$( 'input#clone' ).click(
    function()
    {
      $( 'form#old textarea' ).text( $( 'form#old textarea' ).val() )
      $("form#old").clone().attr( 'id', 'new_form' ).appendTo("body")

    }
)
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jux3e/

Answer (score 4):

Another easy fix for the textarea values not being cloned is to include the following JavaScript file in your HTML: https://github.com/spencertipping/jquery.fix.clone

It just patches the clone method so you can include the file and then forget it's there. Apparently there is a problem with cloneing select values too and this same file fixes that problem as well.

This file was linked to from: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3016. The bug is 4 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this jQuery Plugin.

```
/**
 * clone element, including the textarea part
 */


$.fn.clone2 = function(val1, val2) {
    // ret for return value, cur for current jquery object
    var ret, cur;
    ret = $(this).clone(val1, val2);
    cur = $(this);

    // copy all value of textarea
    ret.find('textarea').each(function() {
        var value_baru;

        // use name attribute as unique id
        value_baru = sek.find('[name="$name"]'.replace('$name', $(this).attr('name')))
                        .val();

        // set the new value to the textarea
        $(this).val(value_baru);
    });

    // return val
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem and wrote this wrapper:

```
$.fn.cloneField = function(withDataAndEvents) {
var clones = [];
this.each(function(){
    var cln = $(this).clone(withDataAndEvents);
    cln.val($(this).val());
    clones.push(cln.get(0));
});
return jQuery( clones ); };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to duplicate the field itself, check this tinny function [relCopy](http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to copy textarea values

```
clonedObject.find(textareaObject).val(originalObject.find(textareaObject).val());
```