# How to add same from input area when user press a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I am doing a form right now, I want to automatically add another input area, same as the line above, when user press a button.

```
 <div class="row" id="1">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">

                        <select class="form-control" id="select">
                            <option selected>Tag Name</option>
                            <option value="p">p</option>
                            <option value="br">br</option>
                        </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                        <select class="form-control" id="class">
                            <option selected>Tag Class</option>
                            <option value="Day">Day</option>
                            <option value="BlockTime">BlockTime</option>
                            <option value="BlockTitle">BlockTitle</option>
                            <option value="Session">Session</option>
                            <option value="Person">Person</option>
                            <option value="Firm">Firm</option>
                        </select>                      
                </div>                    
                <div class="form-group col-lg-7">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea">Please put the content inside this html tag.</textarea>         
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addLine()" value="Add">
                </div>                        
                </div>
```

This is a line of input area, I want to add the same html below the input area we have now when user press the "Add" button. Maybe using JQuery?

[It should looks like this one.](http://screencast.com/t/EVxA2hGZ)

This is what I tried:

```
function addLine() {
$('#1').clone().attr('id', '').appendTo('form');
```

}

For now, it seems work, but how should I do if I want to add id to the new created element, say, 2, 3, 4?

Also I am not sure am I did it the right, or best way.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us what you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250685/is-there-a-way-to-clone-form-field-values-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by jQuery

```
    var n = 8 // adjust it in some way
    var inputArea = ['<div class="form-group col-lg-'+n+'">',
'<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textArea-'+n+'">',// let's be nice and not use same IDs twice
'Please put the content inside this html tag.',
'</textarea></div>'].join('') 
 $('.row').append(inputArea);
```

**However** make sure that your back end is ready to handle that input.

**EDIT:**
The solution might not be fancy and using clone() is completely fine too.
To keep track of ids I would add a simple variable like n that I would increment every time a new input area is added, and then add it to id.

So, init

```
var n = 0;
```

In addLine:

```
n++;
```

Set the id (doable in addLine too)

```
$target.attr('id', 'inputArea-'+n);//Assuming that $target is the inputArea in question
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy from a blueprint structure in the DOM and append your copy after the button.

```
var addline = function() {
    var invisibleNewLine = jQuery('#blueprint').clone();
    var visibleNewLine = invisibleNewLine.removeClass('invisible');
    jQuery('#target').append(visibleNewLine);
};
jQuery('#add-line').click(addline);
```

Remove the `onClick` handler on the element and bind the event using jQuery.

```
<button id="add-line" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
```

See the fiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd32Z/1/)