# Select form elements with filled data

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is really simple.

I use `.html()` to get the html code of a div. The div includes form elements filled by the user.

`.html()` only returns html code and does not retained the filled text.

Is there a way to easily retain/copy the text within the html elements as well?

PS. I already know that

> .val()

will return me the value but I need the

> html code + all values

for in order to copy/paste the form somewhere else.

Comment: Looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) issue. You might want to think about [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: It's possible that you could set a keydown event that update the `value` attribute of the elements like `$("#id").on("keydown", function() { $(this).attr("value", $(this).val()); });` But I don't know if that will work. Alternatively you can use `attr("data-value", ` instead. But again, I don't know that any of that will work for you.

Comment: Hm.. @jwatts1980 that's sound as an interesting approach.

Comment: try this @glarkou http://jsfiddle.net/db9prvmt/. let me know if this works for u

Comment: @Sushil Can we make it work for dropdowns as well?

Comment: it works for dropdowns too. i have a dropdown in the fiddle as well

Comment: oh I didn't test that properly. let me update it

Comment: here you go @glarkou. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/db9prvmt/1/

Comment: @Sushil can you please post it as an answer in order to accept it?

Comment: I've posted my answer @glarkou. please upvote and accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so as @Madness suggested, you can use **[.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** to get the `html` along with the values.

the only thing is that the `select` values don't get cloned (seems to be a known bug in jquery. refer this ticket for more info http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1294). so i've added a workaround to fix this issue. what i do is I take all the select values in a variable before i `clone` like this

```
var selects = $('#myDiv:first').find("select");
```

here `myDiv` is the **id** of the `div`

the final `jquery` code looks like this

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var selects = $('#myDiv:first').find("select");
        var html = $('#myDiv:first').clone(true);


        $(selects).each(function(i) {
            console.log($(this).val());
            var select = this;
            $(html).find("select").eq(i).val($(select).val());
        });
        $('#htmlWithVal').html(html);
    });
});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/db9prvmt/1/)** for the same. hope this helps.

Comment: you're most welcome :) glad was able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You get the values of inputs like this:

```
$('#inputid').val();
```

Where `#inputid` is the id of the input box.

Comment: yes I know that. I need to have the val() within the html code.

Comment: You do it with .clone() There are various approaches depending on your exact case it seems, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250685/is-there-a-way-to-clone-form-field-values-in-jquery-or-javascript)