# get html content after changing selectbox value

Tags: jquery

I am using following function to catch div content.

```
function getHtml(div) {
    div.find("input").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    });
    return div.html();
}
```

and catching data like following

```
var updateSearchContent = getHtml($('#someform'));
```

But if there is any select box in the div and I change its value, the function only catch the initial state with default value.

how can I solve this? If I change select box value it should save the the change value as default.

Comment: why do you do that at all? Can't you use jQuery.serialize() function or something similar? Playing with HTML will cause rerendering all the content again and again

Comment: i have to save this html content to session for further use

Comment: you can save only values in an array in your session and then assign them to the inputs when it is needed. Storing HTML will pollute your session storage with unnecessary content. Also what will happen when you would like to change the initial HTML? The changes won't be visible until the session is expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a select in the div you will need to bind a change event to get the values when it does change:

```
$('#someform').on('change','selecttags', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":selected").val() );
});
```

Note that select does allow multiple values to be selected and thus the return might be an array of values.

Check boxes and radio buttons would also need to be considered if those are included in the form as they have a different set of values.

Just a note from another question:

```
$('select').prop("type");
```

will return either "select-one" or "select-multiple" depending upon the "multiple" attribute

See this question for a full discussion on input type detection: [How to get input type using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165413/how-to-get-input-type-using-jquery/3165569#3165569)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed select element in your loop. Let me know if I am incorrect.

Try this

```
function getHtml(div) {
    div.find("input, textarea, select").each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val());
    });
    return div.html();
}
```

Comment: there is no attribute value on a select / textarea HTML items

Comment: this can be done with .html, but if i want to keep inputs from the form I wrote that function. no relation with putting select there. thanks

Comment: Hey I did not test this but try jquery clone function. https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250685/is-there-a-way-to-clone-form-field-values-in-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have changed getHtml function to following so it can save the selected value within the updated html content.

```
function getHtml(div) {
        div.find("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.is("[type='radio']") || $this.is("[type='checkbox']")) {
                if ($this.prop("checked")) {
                    $this.attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            } else {
                if ($this.is("select")) {
                    $this.find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
                } else {
                    $this.attr("value", $this.val());
                }
            }
        });
        return div.html();
    }
```