# Appending a table row from body tag to another table after updating elements within the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was told it is good practice to never use HTML tags in JavaScript. So I'm trying my very best to execute the following, but I'm not getting what I want.

---

I have 2 tables:

Table #1: a table I use to append rows to.

Table #2: a hidden table that has only 1 row, I use that row to change its content and append it to Table #1

---

Table #1

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table #2

```
<table id='hiddenTable'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="fname"></span></td>
            <td><span id="id"></span></td>
            <td><span id="email"></span></td>
            <td><span id="pnumber"></span></td>
            <td><span id="job"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Append Function

```
function addRow(data){
    $('#fname').text(data.fname);
    $('#id').text(data.id);
    $('#email').text(data.email);
    $('#pnumber').text(data.pnumber);
    $('#job').text(data.job);
    var row = $('#hiddenTable').children('tbody').children('tr:first').clone();
    $('#myTable > tbody:last-child').append(row);
}
```

All the snaps are updated everytime addRow() is executed, but when retrieving the row element from the hidden table, it remains empty, unchanged.

please explain why is this happening? and help me make this work without using html tags in javascript and without using the insert row function.

Comment: How are you retrieving elements from the hidden table?

Comment: Shouldn't `v.job` be a `data.job` like others?

Comment: i feel its issue with your `data` that you are passing into the function. Otherwise don't see any other issue with code except pointed out by @MikhailChurbanov.

Comment: Cloning does not clone dynamically set form element values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250685/is-there-a-way-to-clone-form-field-values-in-jquery-or-javascript Plus, after executing your code once, you would have duplicate IDs, but IDs must be unique within a document.

Comment: still not working for me.

Comment: @vijayP that's what I'm thinking, I don't know how to get around this and the link you provided doesn't really make sense for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @CBroe; the main issue is duplicate ids getting assigned to DOM element. To overcome that first change hidden table's HTML a bit to have `class` instead of `id`. Please have a look at below snippet:

```js
function addRow(data) {

  //first clone the row from hidden table
  var row = $('#hiddenTable').children('tbody').children('tr:first').clone();
  
  //find the span having unique class assigned to them and then set the value
  row.find('.fname').text(data.fname);
  row.find('.id').text(data.id);
  row.find('.email').text(data.email);
  row.find('.pnumber').text(data.pnumber);
  row.find('.job').text(data.job);
  
  //append the newly formed row to main table
  $('#myTable  tbody').append(row);
}

$(function() {
  var data1 = {
    fname: "some name",
    id: "some id",
    email: "some@email.com",
    pnumber: "1212121212",
    job: "some job"
  };

  addRow(data1);
  
  var data2 = {
    fname: "some name 22",
    id: "some id 22",
    email: "some22@email.com",
    pnumber: "88888888888888",
    job: "some job 22"
  };

  addRow(data2);
  
});
```

```css
#hiddenTable {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id='hiddenTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="fname">aaaaaa</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="id"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="email"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="pnumber"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="job"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: omg thank you very much! that actually worked, my problem was cloning after changing the data. I should clone first, modify the clone and append it! thanks very much for the help! really much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

All you have done is correct and should work as you expected unless your `data` object's incorrect. Make a console of your `data` object and try to figure out how you can extract property from that.

```js
function addRow(data) {
  $('#fname').text(data.fname);
  $('#id').text(data.id);
  $('#email').text(data.email);
  $('#pnumber').text(data.pnumber);
  $('#job').text(data.job);
  var row = $('#hiddenTable tr').first().clone();
  $('#myTable tbody').append(row);
}

var data = {
  fname: 'first name',
  id: '12121',
  email: 'email@gmail.com',
  pnumber: '111111111',
  job: 'my job'
}

addRow(data);
```

```css
#hiddenTable {

  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id='hiddenTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="fname"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="id"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="email"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="pnumber"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="job"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: my problem was cloning after modifying which didn't work for me, I should clone first and modify the clone! but thanks though ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smq8f2n7/) solution.

I change something on addRow function:

```
function addRow(data){
        $('#hiddenTable #fname').text(data.fname);
        $('#hiddenTable #id').text(data.id);
        $('#hiddenTable #email').text(data.email);
        $('#hiddenTable #pnumber').text(data.pnumber);
        $('#hiddenTable #job').text(data.job);
        var row = $('#hiddenTable tbody').html();
        $('#myTable > tbody').append(row);
    }
```

Comment: correct answer  by @vijayP . I tried what you suggested before. thanks though <3