# How can I move a DOM section including current form field values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Copying `$('#id').html()` doesn't transfer new textbox values.

How can I make sure these are copied / moved to another DOM-position?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to clone form field values in jQuery or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250685/is-there-a-way-to-clone-form-field-values-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: solved with $(this).contents().appendTo($('#'+sTarget));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make a round-trip through markup, just use `$()` to select the elements and `appendTo` to append them elsewhere (which will move, not copy, them):

```
$("selector-for-the-elements").appendTo("selector-for-the-destination");
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".move").val("move me");
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".move").appendTo(".into");
}, 800);
```

```css
.into {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="move">
<div class="into">Into me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that if the second selector matches *more than one target*, then for the second, third, etc. copy, clones will be made; but the originals will be in the first/only target.

Or of course, use `$()` to select the destination, `$()` to select the elements, and `append` to move them:

```
$("selector-for-the-destination").append($("selector-for-the-elements"));
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".move").val("move me");
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".into").append($(".move"));
}, 800);
```

```css
.into {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="move">
<div class="into">Into me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, great. However, how to append only the contents of the id (div) and not the id itself? Move once works great, move back gives me Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

Comment: @Teson: Use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) depending on your needs (probably `contents`) to select the *children* (or *contents* of the div with that ID instead of that div itself.

Comment: Exellent. JS is not my domain. Best regards /T